# How to find the domain of $\,\csc^{-1}\!\!\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)\;?$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

How to find the domain of

$$\csc^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)$$

My attempt :

the cosecant function lies in $\,\Bbb R\setminus(-1,1)\;$ ,

so first checking the range of $\;\dfrac{x+1}{x}\;$ ,

we find that it covers all reals but $1$.

Thus the domain of the function must be $\,\Bbb R\setminus(-1,1)$.

But this is wrong.

Why is this so ?

***Source*** : *JEE Mains ,2021, august attempt*

Comment: You must find, for what values of $x$, is it true that $\frac{x+1}{x} \in \mathbb R \setminus (-1,1)$. The entire range of $\frac{x+1}{x}$ isn't important : it's only those values that lie in $\mathbb R \setminus (-1,1)$ as well. For example, if $x  = -1$ then $\frac{x+1}{x} = 0$ is in the range of $x$ , but not in the domain of $cosec^{-1}$ , so $x=-1$ cannot be in the domain of the big function.

Comment: I'm unable to understand why, could you explain please?

Comment: oh see, thanks! Merry Christmas.

Comment: Ah great, Merry Christmas to you as well. Consider editing your question by adding a source for this question (name of textbook, problem number etc.) and/or similar questions on this site or in the same book that you've seen before and tried to imitate. This is referred to as context and is important for general improvement of questions on MSE. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/) for more details (and see you as well, I need to leave).

Comment: I forgo to. Will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the domain of the function $\;\color{blue}{\csc^{-1}}$ is $\;\color{brown}{\Bbb R\setminus(-1,1)}\,,\;$ that is $\;\color{brown}{\big(\!-\!\infty,-1\big]\cup\big[1,+\infty\big)}\,,\;$ you should solve the following inequalities :

$\dfrac{x+1}x\leqslant-1\quad\lor\quad\dfrac{x+1}x\geqslant1\;.$

The solutions of the first inequality are :

$S_1=\left[-\dfrac12,0\right)\;$.

The solutions of the second inequality are :

$S_2=\big(0,+\infty\big)\;.$

Hence , the domain of the function $\;f(x)=\csc^{-1}\!\left(\dfrac{x+1}x\right)\;$ is

$\left[-\dfrac12,0\right)\cup\big(0,+\infty\big)\;.$

Comment: I see, thanks!!